# How to get other values in dictionary then one value equals

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, for-loop

I have a list of dictionaries. I want to get the value of the dictionary pair when the value of another is 'x'

```
alphabets = [
              {"name": "abc", "value": "first_three"}, 
              {"name": "mno", "value": "middle"}, 
              {"name": "xyz", "value": "last_three"}
            ]
```

How do I get the `first_three` when `abc`.

THis is what I am doing but I am not getting any results.

```
res = [ sub['name'] for sub in d['alphabets'] ]
            if res == 'abc':
               val = [ sub['value'] for sub in d['alphabets'] ]
               print(val)
```

I am not getting any results back. How do I get the `first_three` when `name == 'abc`

Comment: Try something like this: `values_where_names_are_abc = [_['value'] for _ in list_dict if _['name'] == 'abc']`.

Comment: It would be good if you edit your post and be consistent with the variable names you mentioned. Your list of dictionaries is `list_dict` but in your code you are mentioning `d['alphabet']` and `sub['name']`. That makes it hard to understanding the logic you are trying to achieve.

Comment: If the names are unique, I would suggest using a dict of dicts with the names as keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a list comprehension:

```
res = [d['value'] for d in list_dict if d['name'] == 'abc']
```

---

```
>>> print(res)
['first_three']
```

Comment: Should note that this list comprehension does not have any break condition, so for long lists it keeps looking even after finding the correct name (assuming names are unique in the list).

Answer (score 2):

```
for d in list_dict:
  if d['name'] == 'abc':
    print d['value']
```

I don't really understand the strategy you are using in your code that's not working, but one thing I can tell you is that `res == 'abc'` will never be true, because you are setting `res` to a list on line one.